# haddop/mapreduce local job directories are not deleted

Tags: hadoop

I just started using hadoop and I noticed that local job directories are not deleted.
I am using hadoop 2.2.0 on Windows .

Is there any configuration that's needed so hadoop can do the clean up of all directories under “/tmp/hadoop-*/mapred/local/*”?

Also, after investigating and looking in the code, I found that part of the logic is in the the class “org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner” (hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0)

```
try {
  fs.delete(systemJobFile.getParent(), true); // delete submit dir
  localFs.delete(localJobFile, true); // delete local copy
  // Cleanup distributed cache
  localDistributedCacheManager.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  LOG.warn("Error cleaning up "+id+": "+e);
}
```

Why not just use (as it's the case for systemJobFile):

localFs.delete(localJobFile.getParent(), true); // delete local copy

Is it correct to do that?
I try it and looks like it's fixing the issue, but I am not sure.

Update: I just noticed that a lot of directories "attempy_local****" are still there. Not deleted by hadoop!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I have to find a quick solution and I don't like the idea to create a script to clean-up these directories, I did this patch (org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner):
    // line: 114
    private Path localCacheJobDir;

```
// line: 156
    this.localCacheJobDir = localFs.makeQualified(new Path(new Path(new Path(conf.getLocalPath(jobDir), user), JOBCACHE), jobid.toString()));

// line: 492
    try {
      fs.delete(systemJobFile.getParent(), true); // delete submit dir

      final Path localJobFilePath = localJobFile.getParent();
      localFs.delete(localJobFile, true); // delete local copy

      // Cleanup distributed cache
      localDistributedCacheManager.close();

      localFs.delete(localJobFilePath, true); // delete local copy

      localFs.delete(localCacheJobDir, true); // delete local copy
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.warn("Error cleaning up "+id+": "+e);
    }
```

I have never worked with hadoop before and I just started playing with in the last two days, so I don't know if my solution won't have any impact on hadoop. Unfortunatly this is the best solution I have.

Answer (score 0):

There are some configuration keys like

```
mapreduce.task.files.preserve.failedtasks
```

in mapred config.

Anyway...
By default hadoop should clear the temporary job directory.
On success the files are moved to `${mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir}`
If things gone wrong, files are deleted.
So I'm not sure this fix for real what is happening on your installation.